# Overriding of CorpusView.read_block() not taken into account

Tags: python-3.x, overriding, nltk, subclass

I want to process a bunch of text files using NLTK, splitting them on a particular keyword.  I am therefore trying to "*subclass `StreamBackedCorpusView`, and override the `read_block()` method*", as suggested [by the documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#writing-new-corpus-readers).

```
class CustomCorpusView(StreamBackedCorpusView):

    def read_block(self, stream):
        block = stream.readline().split()
        print("wtf")
        return [] # obviously this is only for debugging

class CustomCorpusReader(PlaintextCorpusReader):
    CorpusView = CustomCorpusViewer
```

However my knowledge of inheritance is rusty, and it seems my overriding is not taken into account.  The output of

```
corpus = CustomCorpusReader("/path/to/files/", ".*")

print(corpus.words())
```

is identical to the output of

```
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader("/path/to/files", ".*")

print(corpus.words())
```

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but what ?

Comment: Oh there's a way! Let me find some time to answer later on if no one answers =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#writing-new-corpus-readers) actually suggests two ways of defining a custom corpus view :

> 1. Call the StreamBackedCorpusView constructor, and provide your block reader function via the block_reader argument.
> 2. Subclass StreamBackedCorpusView, and override the read_block() method.

It also suggests the first way is easier, and indeed I managed to get it working as the following :

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.corpus.reader.api import *

class CustomCorpusReader(PlaintextCorpusReader):

    def _custom_read_block(self, stream):
        block = stream.readline().split()
        print("wtf")
        return [] # obviously this is only for debugging

    def custom(self, fileids=None):
        return concat(
            [
                self.CorpusView(fileid, self._custom_read_block, encoding=enc)
                for (fileid, enc) in self.abspaths(fileids, True)
            ]
        )


corpus = CustomCorpusReader("/path/to/files/", ".*")

print(corpus.custom())
```